# Целесообразность исключений во внутренних классах

Tags: исключения

Допустим наша задача -- реализовать класс A решающий некую задачу. И этот класс не должен кидать исключений просто потому, что такова природа решаемой им задачи.

Но класс А использует вспомогательный класс B, на который можно подать некорректные параметры. С одной стороны хорошо бы в этом случае кинуть исключение, облегчив последующую отладку, а с другой -- никто кроме нас этот класс использовать не будет и тратить машинное время на лишние проверки совершенно ни к чему.

Быть такому исключению или не быть?

Вопрос касается только языков не поддерживающих debug/release выборку кода (ifdef в С++).

**Утрированный пример**: консольная программа, в которую мы вводим площадь квадрата и получаем длину его стороны. Причём ввод площади фильтруется так, что пользователь не может ввести некорректное значение. Нужно ли в функции sqrt, которую мы почему-то написали сами, делать проверку на отрицательность аргумента и кидать в этом случае исключение?

Если писать эту проверку -- будет легче отлавливать внутренние ошибки программиста, но в релиз-версии проверка окажется уже лишней.

Comment: Все же о каких именно языках идет речь?

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, спасибо. Ответ на вопрос действительно сводится к более внимательному поиску аналогов ifdef'а. И почти во все языках они, хоть и не в явной форме, но присутствуют. Преобразуйте комментарий в ответ.

Comment: А мне было бы интересно узнать, какие аналоги ifdef есть, например, в Java?

Comment: @mikillskegg, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813853/ifdef-ifndef-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Исключение кидать нужно в любом случае. Это сообщит тебе что у класса В проблемы, а в классе А её нужно попытаться разрешить либо просто проглотить и проигнорировать

Comment: И как вы, простите, собираетесь обрабатывать проблему передачи некорректных параметров? А игнорирование ничем не отличается от варианта "без исключения", кроме как затратой лишнего процессорного времени.

Comment: Если есть риск получения некорректных данных, то обработка исключения должна быть обязательной, иначе ваш программный продукт даже и мечтать не сможет о release-ветке. ИМХО естественно.

Comment: @Shamanis, как уже было сказано класс A изолирован, что исключает некорректные данные. Но некорректные данные могут возникнуть внутри программы из-за ошибки программиста.

Comment: Не согласен с @АО )):

ИМХО: Пока склоняюсь к двум версиям класса: B и safeB...  A использует B...

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, какую-то проверочку стоит сделать, хотя бы во время разработки и тестирования.

Comment: А теперь представьте, что у вас в проекте мегабайты кода, и пришло время выпускать релиз-версию. Будите писать парсер и вводить в коде специальные //дебаг-метки?

Answer (score 0):

Из Вашего вопроса, ответов и Ваших комментариев к ним не совсем ясно, Вы опасаетесь не выявленных при отладке ошибок в релиз-версии ?

Т.е. в "боевом" режиме неправильные параметры исключены, а оставшийся от отладки код впустую жрет ресурсы.

Уточните, пожалуйста, свой вопрос безотносительно к исключениям. Иногда ведь ошибки входных данных удобней отлавливать перехватом исключения.

Comment: Добавил пример. Надеюсь это прояснит вопрос.

Comment: Абсолютно прояснил. Вот жалко, \#ifdef Вам не подходит. 

Что-то надо думать о структуре кода, так что бы легко уживались релизная о отладочная версии. Да, 2 версии (все равно, по жизни, для мегабайтного проекта этих версий наплодится...).